# Change UILabel in loop

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I want to change the UILabel after 2 sec in a loop.
But current code change it to last value after loop finished.

```
- (IBAction) start:(id)sender{


   for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    NSString *tempStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", @" "];

    int randomNumber = 1+ arc4random() %(3);

    if (randomNumber == 1) {
        tempStr = @"Red";
    }else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        tempStr = @"Blue";
    } else {
        tempStr = @"Green";
    }
       NSLog(@"log: %@ ", tempStr);
       labelsText.text = tempStr;
       [tempStr release];
        sleep(2);

    }
}
```

Comment: NEVER sleep the main thread. It blocks your whole app, including UI updates.

Comment: also this line is redundant - NSString *tempStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", @" "];, you overwrite tempStr value later anyway and string you created leaks, just write NSString *tempStr = nil instead. (and remove [tempStr release]; as well)

Answer (score 2):

Your code updates label to last value only as your function blocks main thread so UI cannot get updated. To solve that problem move your updating code to separate function and call it using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method. (or schedule calls using `NSTimer`)

Possible solution (you will also need to handle the case when user taps your button several times in a row, but that should not be too difficult):

```
- (IBAction) start:(id)sender{
    [self updateLabel];
}

- (void) updateLabel{
   static const NSString* allStrings[] = {@"Red", @"Blue", @"Green"};
   static int count = 0;

   int randomNumber = arc4random()%3;
   NSString *tempStr = allStrings[randomNumber];

   NSLog(@"log: %@ ", tempStr);
   labelsText.text = tempStr;

   ++count;
   if (count)
      [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction) start:(id)sender{
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {

    int randomNumber = 1+ arc4random() %(3);
    NSString *tempStr = @"";
    if (randomNumber == 1) {
        tempStr = @"Red";
    }else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        tempStr = @"Blue";
    } else {
        tempStr = @"Green";
    }
    [labelsText performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:tempStr afterDelay:i * 2]
       NSLog(@"log: %@ ", tempStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sleep()` to perform actions after a delay, it blocks the whole thread.  Use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` instead.  As you are probably running this on the main thread, `sleep()` will block any UI updates until after the whole loop has run, so the only thing you see is the last update.  As a general rule of thumb, assume that the UI doesn't ever get updated until after the app has finished executing your method.

You shouldn't use `%s` as the format specifier for an `NSString`, that's the format specifier for a C string.  You should use `%@` instead.  In fact, if all you are doing is initialising the string with an `NSString` literal, there's no need to use `initWithFormat` at all, you can just use the literal itself.

You've also got big memory problems.  At the beginning of the loop, you allocate memory for an instance of `NSString` that is a single space.  You then overwrite the pointer to this memory when you assign to `tempStr` again, meaning you leak the original allocation of memory.  *Build and Analyze* will find problems like this for you.  Then you release `tempStr`, but as the second assignment to this pointer variable was to an autoreleased `NSString`, the instance will be released one time too many when the autorelease pool gets drained, which will probably manifest itself as a crash that's impossible to debug a little later in the app.

I'd do something like this:

```
- (void)showRandomColourAfterDelay {
    static NSUInteger count = 0;
    switch (arc4random()%3) {
        case 0:
            labelsText.text = @"Red";
        case 1:
            labelsText.text = @"Blue";
        case 2:
            labelsText.text = @"Green";
    }
    count++;
    if (count >= 3) return;
    [self performSelector:@selector(showRandomColourAfterDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}
```

In fact, I'd probable use an `NSArray` to hold the colour strings, but that would involve changes outside of a single method, so I've stuck with your hard-coding approach.